# How do you simplify a radical equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am having trouble figuring out how this equation was simplified. I have looked everywhere on the internet. No luck. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: What equation?  I don't see one.

Comment: Your original post had reference to the problem of presumably finding the real value(s) of $x$ such that $8=\sqrt{3x}$.  First, notice that $x$ must be positive (*otherwise you are taking the square root of a negative number*).  Next, you can square each side, giving $(8)^2=\left(\sqrt{3x}\right)^2$ or in other words $64 = 3x$.  Continue from there.

Comment: Now that you have posted the image, we see that in fact you did not mean to have $\sqrt{3x}$ (*where both the $3$ AND the $x$ are under the radical*) but rather you meant to have $\sqrt{3} \times x$ (*where the $x$ is outside of the radical*).  You can continue exactly as you would if these were integers or rational numbers.  $8=\sqrt{3}~x$, you can divide both sides by $\sqrt{3}$ to get $\frac{8}{\sqrt{3}} = x$.  From here, if you so desire, you can "*multiply the left side by $1$*" to simplify, here by multiplying by $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}}$ and continuing to simplify.

Comment: Hi, I got the same answer. 64=3x but then on the book is showing something else. I added a picture, please kindly see it. Thank you

Comment: They are just rationalizing the denominator by multiplying the top and bottom by $\sqrt 3$

Comment: Thank you Andrew. The problem was that I though the the x was inside the radical which it wasn't. Thank you again. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

$$8=\sqrt 3x\iff x = \frac{8}{\sqrt 3}\iff x = \frac{8}{\sqrt 3}\frac{\sqrt 3}{\sqrt 3}=\frac {8\sqrt 3} 3 $$

Comment: Perfect.! thank you

Comment: @user2984143 That's a standard manipulation. Another similar is for example $$\frac1{\sqrt 2+1}=\frac1{\sqrt 2+1}\frac{\sqrt 2-1}{\sqrt 2-1}=\frac{\sqrt 2-1}{2-1}={\sqrt 2-1}$$ using that $(A+B)(A-B)=A^2-B^2$.